# Unable to combine two linq results in one var

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight

I have two linq results and I want to combine them in one var. How can I achieve this?

```
 var xAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new { x.ConceptId1, x.ConceptDisplay1 }).Distinct();
 var yAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new { x.ConceptId2, x.ConceptDisplay2 }).Distinct();
```

xAxisconceptIdsAndName returns (1,"a") and yAxisconceptIdsAndName returns (2,"b"). I want them in one result like (1,"a"),(2,"b"), etc.

Results:

Approach - 1:

```
var conceptIdsAndName = Enumerable.Union(xAxisconceptIdsAndName, yAxisconceptIdsAndName);
```

Error:

```
 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Approach - 2:

```
var conceptIdsAndName = xAxisconceptIdsAndName.Union(yAxisconceptIdsAndName);
```

Error:

```
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the type of `_analysisResult`?

Comment: Its an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Concat` method. `var conceptIdsAndName = xAxisconceptIdsAndName.Concat(yAxisconceptIdsAndName);`

Comment: I tried that also. It gives the same error like I got in approach 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anonymous types have different properties, and thus are different types.  If you make the properties identical in name, type, and order, the same type will be used, allowing you to combine them into a single sequence of that anonymous type.

```
var xAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new 
    { 
        ConceptId = x.ConceptId1, 
        ConceptDisplay = x.ConceptDisplay1 
    }).Distinct();
var yAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new 
    { 
        ConceptId = x.ConceptId2, 
        ConceptDisplay = x.ConceptDisplay2 
    }).Distinct();
var combined = xAxisconceptIdsAndName.Concat(yAxisconceptIdsAndName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a non-anonymous type in your select statements, which will cause the types to match in your `Union` call.

Create a type to hold your result, and use that for the X and Y axis data.

For example, given:

```
 class AxisData : IEquatable<AxisData>
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Display { get; set; } // Should be the type of ConceptDisplay1 & 2

     // Implement IEquatable<AxisData>
 }
```

You could write:

```
 var xAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new AxisData { Id = x.ConceptId1, Display = x.ConceptDisplay1 }).Distinct();
 var yAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => new AxisData { Id = x.ConceptId2, Display = x.ConceptDisplay2 }).Distinct();
```

And then your `Union` call will work properly.

Comment: You need to specify the property names when using than object initializer like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Tuple` instead of the `anonymous types`:

```
var xAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => 
    new Tuple<int,string> (x.ConceptId1, x.ConceptDisplay1)).Distinct();
var yAxisconceptIdsAndName = _analysisResult.Select(x => 
    new Tuple<int,string> (x.ConceptId2, x.ConceptDisplay2)).Distinct();

var union = xAxisconceptIdsAndName.Union(yAxisconceptIdsAndName);
```

The `anonymous types` are considdered as different by the compiler and so cannot be used in a `Union` statement